# change the value of all duplicates in a python list

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures

I have a list in python like

```
[{key1: valuea1, key2:valueb1}, {key1: valuea2, key2: valueb2}, ....{key1: valueaN, key2: valuebN}]
```

What's the efficient way of, say, multiplying by -1 all the valuebs where valuea occurs more than one time.

For example:

```
[{key1: 5, key2:8}, {key1: 2, key2: 4}, {key1: 5, key2: 4}]
```

becomes:

```
[{key1: 5, key2:-8}, {key1: 2, key2: 4}, {key1: 5, key2: -4}]
```

Looking for something built into python/ better algorithm than just looping through the list twice.

Thanks!

Comment: There is none, it's a programming implementation that has to be done on your part to correlate your **dictionary** items, its keys and values against the next in the lists items and its keys and values and so on.. It's just a mess to begin with IMO.

Comment: Your best bet, is to check if `'key2'` exists already in one of the other **dictionaries** within the **list**, and if so, increment by 1 or something i dunno..

Comment: you have misread the question...i am looking for something better than a naive looping through the list twice solution.

Comment: You've must have miss-read my comment, you **have** to loop through the list and then the dictionary if you want a **dynamic** way of modifying your values, see @thg435's solution if you want a static way to modify `'key1' | 'key2'`.

Answer (score 3):

Since you're looking for an one-pass algorithm, it could be like this:

```
def invert_dupes(lst):
    pos = {}
    for n, e in enumerate(lst):
        k = e['key1']
        if k in pos:
            if pos[k] >= 0:
                lst[pos[k]]['key2'] *= -1
                pos[k] = -1
            e['key2'] *= -1
        else:
            pos[k] = n
    return lst
```

For each "key" value we remember the position it occurred for the first time and if it comes again, invert that position and all subsequent ones.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick, although it does go through the list twice. First, make a list of all key1s. Then for every dictionary in the list, check whether its key1 value occurs more than once. If so, multiply the value for key2 by -1.

```
myList = [{"key1": 5, "key2":-8}, {"key1": 2, "key2": 4}, {"key1": 5, "key2": -4}]
valueAs = [x["key1"] for x in myList]

for x in myList:
    if valueAs.count(x["key1"]) > 1:
        x["key2"] *= -1
```

You could improve the efficiency for a large list of dictionaries somewhat by user a `Counter` instead of the list's `count()`. This way the number of occurences of each value is only computed once.

```
from collections import Counter
valueAs = Counter([x["key1"] for x in myList])

for x in myList:
    if valueAs[x["key1"]] > 1:
        x["key2"] *= -1
```

Comment: you sure this does not multiply by -1**numofoccurences instead of just -1?

Comment: Ah, it should of course change the value of key2, not key1, edited. But otherwise it works fine; as every dictionary in the list is visited once.

Answer (score -1):

```
from collections import Counter
valueAs = Counter([x["key1"] for x in myList])

for x in myList:
    if valueAs[x["key1"]] > 1:
        x["key2"] *= -1
```

Comment: Did you just copy this from my answer?

Comment: @Junuxx your answer was buggy, u didn't even tested it, I fixed it as I was thinking along the same line and after that u copied my answer.

Comment: Yes there were a few typos, you could have pointed them out. Fixing an obvious typo in your own work is not copying.